# How to use camera intent in Android child activity of Activity Group

Tags: android

I have an ActivityGroup named "BigActivity" which had one child activity named "CHACtivity".

I need to capture camera image from child activity. I called camera intent  by calling startActivityForResult(), but onActivityResult() is not called in that situation in childactivity. I tried to override onActivityResult() in BigActivity which extends ActivityGroup like the below:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
    {
        Activity activity = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();
        activity.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        
      
    }
}
```

This is showing error as "The method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) from the type Activity is not visible".

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you solved your problem ? If then how ? I have the same problem ..... :(

Answer (score 0):

ActivityGroup is now [Deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html). You should use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) instead. I'm afraid that's my best advice on working with activity groups.

If you're capturing an image from an external activity that implements the standard behavior of [MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), then you can retrieve your photo from the Intent in the documented ways.

Basically, your best bet is to store the photo in a JPEG file and read it from the calling activity.